# .htaccess URL Rewriting for Folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an app located at `example.com/app` with `signin.php`, `signup.php`, `index.php`, etc inside the folder.

Now the client wants to have the app accessible at `example.com/signin.php` and so on, but I want to keep the app files inside the app folder for better management.

I tried using this, and it works, but then I can't access the files that I already had in the root directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/
RewriteRule (.*) /app/$1
```

Is there a way to exclude pages in the root directory from being affected? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/
RewriteRule (.*) /app/$1
```

Using -f and -d makes sure it doesn't mess up any existing files or directories.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just get you http server to point tot he app folder as the base?

Answer (score 0):

Consult the documentation of apaches mod_rewrite, look at the RewriteMap directive. Using that you can easily name all names you want to or you do not want to be rewritten.